# How to hide images from unregistered users

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I made a website to share pictures like films but i have problems with privacy. When u create a photo film u can share its url with people but people who are not logged in my website they still can watch my film   http://thephotofilm.com/films/1002947

```
SELECT path FROM images WHERE img_id=(id)
if($type=="ole")
$type=1;
else
$type=1;
if(!is_numeric($imageIndex) || $imageIndex<0)
invalidImage();
```

If user is not logged in display a blank picture

Thanks in advace!

Comment: Are you using session to check if the user is logged, what are you using to check the loggin?

Comment: you have to do it in the server, if you do it in the browser you wont hide anything

Answer (score 3):

you do it with `$_session['username']`.

```
  if(isset($_session['username'])){   //change this session to your session name.
      echo 'show image here';
     }
     else{
      echo 'tell him wtf are you doing here';
      }
```

Comment: @EmilioGort hehehe most they use username :) , but i told him to change it to his name :).

Answer (score 3):

I would use a session variable to check against. If the user has a valid session, show the image. If not, do not show the image.

Something like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['my-session-var']
{
    echo '<img src="my-image.jpg" />';
}
else
{
    echo '<p>You gotta log in first, ya \'doofis!</p>';
}
```